# migrate from progressdb to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, etl, progress-db

I am looking out for a solution to migrate data from Progressdb to MySQL..Please let me know if there are any solutions for the same.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time thing then the answer above is probably best (dump to ascii and import, or link the tables).

If it is more of a replication oriented problem then you might find http://www.bravepoint.com/products-pro2-replication-suite.shtml to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you sir..is there a open source solution for the same problem? since my job necessitates me to implement the solution without spending extra resources for the same. Please guide me further.Thank you very much for the guidance and support.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities

- Export to flat file and import to MySQL
- link tables from both databases in Microsoft Access via ODBC, and then xfer data using SQL